# Why the unknown error?

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, server

This is my error message:

> ColdFusion could not delete the file
>   C:\path\guid.png
>   for an unknown reason.

I've already checked to make sure my coldFusion user has permission to do so, as suggested [here](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/236575). That is not the problem, the user has all the permissions. Unfortunately, the code is breaking on production servers, and **not** my own local server (could be relevant). Production is on CF11 but I am on CF9.

Here is the code:

```
<cffunction name="svgToPDF" access="public" output="false" returntype="string">
    <cfargument name="svg" required="true" type="string" />

    <cfset var local = {} />
    <cfset local.guid = CreateUUID() />
    <cfset local.outPDF = ExpandPath(local.guid & '.pdf') />

    <cfset local.svg = DeserializeJSON(exportToImage(svg=arguments.svg)) />

    <cfif local.svg.error>
        <!-- Conversion error -->
        <cfset FileDelete(#local.svg.file#) />
        <cfreturn '' />
    </cfif>

    <!--- rotate the png --->
    <cfimage
        action="read"
        source="#local.svg.file#"
        name="local.objImage" />

    <cfimage
        action="rotate"
        source="#local.objImage#"
        angle="90"
        name="local.objImage" />

    <cfimage
        action="write"
        source="#local.objImage#"
        destination="#local.svg.file#"
        overwrite="yes" />

    <!--- Add the png to the pdf, write the pdf file, and delete the png --->
    <cfscript>
        img = CreateObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.Image");
        png = img.getInstance(local.svg.file);

        document = CreateObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.Document");
        document.init(png);
        fileIO = CreateObject("java", "java.io.FileOutputStream");
        fileIO.init(local.outPDF);
        writer = CreateObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter");
        writer.getInstance(document, fileIO);
        document.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        document.open();
        document.add(png);
        document.close();

        FileDelete(#local.svg.file#); <!--- This is the line where it breaks--->
    </cfscript>

    <cfreturn local.outPDF />

</cffunction>
```

How can I fix this function?
Thanks

Comment: I know it's not the error, but your comment on the line that breaks in the example is an invalid comment for cfscript. Should start with `//` or wrapped in `/* */`

Comment: What happens if you dump/log a `fileExists(local.svg.file)` right before you delete? And can you see if the file is actually being written on the server?

Comment: Couple of other notes: You have extra #'s that you don't need (e.g. use `fileDelete(local.svg.file)` instead of `fileDelete(#local.svg.file#)` ), and the `LOCAL` scope in a function is already thread safe (var-scoped). No need to do `<cfset var local = {} />`(unless you're on an old version of CF)

Comment: If you're on Windows, it's likely file system locks on the file.

Comment: Agreed, it does sound like something is locking the file. A) Does the error stack trace contain more details? B) Does it happen every time in prod? C) For grins, any change if you temporarily use a byte array ie `bytes = fileReadBinary(local.svg.file); img.getInstance(javacast("byte[]", bytes ));` instead of loading from a file here `img.getInstance(local.svg.file)` ?

Comment: If this is CF 10 / 11 then this is a bug that has been mentioned here - https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=4031026

Comment: @beloitdavisja If I do a dump locally it says the file exists, but I can't make changes to production servers so easily

Comment: @haxtbh That is most likely the problem, production is on CF11 but I am on CF9. If you make that an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: *production is on CF11 but I am on CF9* Can I ask why? Running a different version than production is just asking for problems..

Comment: @Leigh I agree. Some of our prod servers are on cf9, some on cf11. Some devs are on cf11, some on cf9. We are in the process of moving everyone to 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you production server is CF11 then this is a bug that has been mentioned here, in Bug# 4031026  - http://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=4031026

The bug has been verified by Adobe and fix will be due, most probably in their next hotfix.

JPEG seems to be the only format that works at the moment without locking issues.